# Get user information out of the database and display on Google Maps?

Tags: c#, facebook, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, facebook-c#-sdk

I have got a Facebook page so when they like it and accept permissions they get issued an access token and then their details are captured in a database that I have set up in ASP.NET MVC 3 C#. Now I want to get that data out and place them on [Google Maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Maps) which will be like embedded on the Facebook page?

Is this possible to do? I can set a default marker with a popup text box, but now I want to display all users who have liked my Facebook page on Google Maps. It sounds confusing, I know.

(I was redirected here when accessing the Facebook developer forum.)

Comment: Do you capture their location, pref. as location coordinates?

Comment: yeh capture the lang and long co-ordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have the Facebook user's location information, it's basically a problem related to Google Maps. You can check out how to plot multiple markers on a single Google map, check out the Google Maps API documentation. And if you like instant results, you may check out *[Simple map with marker](http://gmap.nurtext.de/examples.html)* (see the examples section, the markers are basically a collections of co-ordinates).

Comment: i also found this as well http://www.facebook.com/login.php?v=1.0&next=&api_key=a9e50199566e7ebcfa8d0013cccb575d

definitely the same thing i want to happen. quite cool that, i know it can be done now will just read the documentation in depth thanks Hasin